# Grails Integration Tests with Maven

Tags: testing, grails, maven, integration

First of all, I am shocked at the lack of documentation for implementing front-end tests for Grails. The GroovyPagesTestCase class makes testing super easy, so easy there is no excuse for FE Devs not to test. But anyway, here is my question. At my job, I am running Grails with Maven. When I need to run my tests, the only successful command to execute the tests is:

```
mvn grails:test-app
```

and that runs all tests. But, I really want to move faster when test-driving code, does anyone know how to only run integration tests in this kind of environment? Not finding anything on my own.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you workinh with? We use Grails 2.1.0. All our dependencies are declared in the pom file, and BuildConfig.groovy declares 'pom true'. This allows us to build and test the project with Maven, but also allows us to run and test using the Grails commands.

Comment: we are using pre 2.1.0, 1.7.xx I think I will try our your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The grails command for this is `grails test-app :integration`.

Given that, I believe you should be able to use the grails:exec goal to run an arbitrary command, like this- `mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs=:integration`.

Not quite sure how mvn will handle the colon after the equals sign. You might try quotes or double-quotes around `:integration` if the vanilla syntax won't cut it.

This based on http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#4.5 Ant and Maven.

Update: `grails test-app -unit` and `grails test-app -integration` are also supported, which may be more to Maven's liking.

Comment: `mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs="-integration"` - if you are still skeptical about mvn handling `:` :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Grails 1.x

```
mvn -Dargs=CircleTests -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
mvn grails:test-app will always execute all tests
```

Best combine that with `-unit` / `-integration` to avoid the time-consuming preparation for the other phase (example uses a test named `CircleTests`; drop the suffix in the arguments):

```
mvn -Dargs="-unit Circle" -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
```

You may use patterns and multiple names, separated by spaces:

```
mvn "-Dargs=Square Ci*le" -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
```

Grails also understands the special -unit and -integration names:

```
mvn -Dargs=-unit -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
```

Or to run a single method:

```
mvn -Dargs=Circle.DrawSmallEllipse -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
```

#### Grails 2.x

With the new Grails version this does not work any more because grails:exec runs in dev mode instead of test mode. You can now execute either of:

```
mvn -Dgrails.cli.args="integration: Circle" grails:test-app
mvn -Dgrails.cli.args="-integration Circle" grails:test-app
mvn -Dgrails.env=test -Dargs="integration: Circle" -Dcommand=test-app grails:exec
```

Answer (score 0):

On grails 2.x this is what works best for me:

All integration tests:

```
mvn grails:exec -Dgrails.env=test -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs=:integration
```

Single test class:

```
mvn grails:exec -Dgrails.env=test -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs=:integration -Dargs=NameOfYourIntegrationTests
```

Single method in a test class:

```
mvn grails:exec -Dgrails.env=test -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs=:integration -Dargs=NameOfYourIntegrationTests.testMethod
```

Hope it helps